# Including image in SharePoint survey answer and hiding elements only work on the first page

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I would like to add some text/remove some text etc to a sharepoint survey page.
   Which i have done using jquery/jscript.But unfortunately it only works on the first page.
Any ideas how i can get it to work on all the pages?
See a sample here
    http://sharepointkings.blogspot.com.au/2011/05/include-image-in-sharepoint-survey.html

Cheers

Comment: Figured it out.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

edit each page of the survey and add the CEWP(Content Editor Web Part) and insert your java/jquery script as you did on the 1st page.

Answer (score -1):

This is really good solution. It work for me

http://yasingokhanyuksel.blogspot.com.tr/2016/04/sharepoint-survey-image-question.html